# Multiplication counter

Tags: c#, counter

I needed a little help on a project i'm working on. It's probably really easy to figure out, but I don't have a clue on how to do it. So I have a Form which has 2 buttons, 1 text box and one label. I want it so that when I type in a number into the text box,it multiplies itself by two, then keeps adding it to itself. I realize that's a bit confusing.

here's what it is like:  input 2, press, outcome 4, press, outcome 6, press, outcome 8... and so on

how would i do that?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: What have you done so far? If its probably really easy to figure out, why don't you try to figure it out?

Comment: So I've been trying to find out what i'm doing, but I don't have any idea. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Search for "Hello World" and take it from there..

Answer (score 0):

I create a method for the sake of your project LoL,

What this method do is to add current value of`textbox`to current value of `label`.

```
private void SelfAdd(TextBox textBox, Label label)
{
    try
    {
        label.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(label.Text)).ToString();
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You must know how to print "hello,world" first to another method to be able to use this in your procject. :D

Comment: Also take note that `textbox` and `label` must be convertible to integer.